# Getting an error "GitCommandNotFound: Cmd('git') not found due to:" in Anaconda Spyder

Tags: python, anaconda, gitpython

Im Trying to clone a git repo using the GitPython in spyder.
im using the below code.

```
from git import Repo
full_local_path = r'C:/New/Newfolder'
remote = f"https://(git path)/*/frontend_backup.git"
Repo.clone_from(remote, full_local_path)
```

But im getting an error

```
GitCommandNotFound: Cmd('git') not found due to: FileNotFoundError('[WinError 2] The system cannot find the file specified')
  cmdline: git clone -v https://(git path)/*/frontend_backup.git C:/New/Newfolder
```

The same command when executed in Anaconda Prompt, is getting executed successfully, but when tried to do the same in Spyder , getting such error.

Note: I have given the PATH for git.exe and python.exe in system variables.

Answer (score 2):

Found the answer.

Its because the anaconda environment(base) in which i was using the Spyder hadn't installed the git versions.
The base env, doesnt let you install extra packages, you have to create another env and install all the packages needed.
i created another env in anaconda and it solved the error.